# How do I convert Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes to string

Tags: c#, ascii

This is the message Im sending away and I get the wrong answer when I receive it. So how do I get the return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response); as a string when i send it away?

I think its something wrong with the ASCII translation?

```
public byte[] diagnostic()
{
    string response = Send(new byte[] { 0x30 });
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response); // To string?
}
```

Comment: Since you say that the error comes from where you receive it you need to show us that code. It seems like it comes from the Send method. And since that function is returning a string, if there is an error it is inside the Send method (based on the code you have supplied). Also are you sure that you are recieving ascii? Try to give an example of what you do get and what you expected and maybe it will be more clear.

Comment: well Lenny32 solved it

Comment: Why would you convert to bytes then back again? Just return the `string`

Comment: It goes in to a CRC32 Algoritm and then i Flip it back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string response = "Hello world!";
var o = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response); // To string?
var s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(o);
```

Is this answering your question?

Comment: @Andy if someone answered your question you should click the checkmark and mark the answer accepted.